# Sorting a file based on first array element

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a (binary) file which has multiple entries of an array of 6 elements. So the file would be structured something like this :

```
{1 2 12 18 22 0} {11 17 20 19 20 7} {3 9 18 24 0 9}...
```

where I have put brackets around the elements that form one array. I'd like to sort the file based only on the first element of each array, so the sorted file should read

```
{1 2 12 18 22 0} {3 9 18 24 0 9} {11 17 20 19 20 7}...
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you know how each element is serialized (i.e. represented as a sequence of bytes)? For instance, is each element no larger than 255 and stored as a single byte (i.e. the total file size is evenly divisible by 6)?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe - Each element is a 4 byte integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read file into 2 dimensional array. Each element on the first dimension should hold six elements.
2. Implement comparison function for `qsort`.
3. Use `qsort` with your comparision function to sort the array.
4. Write array back to file.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    vector < vector<int> > v;
    vector <int> t;

    t.push_back(4);
    t.push_back(5);
    t.push_back(6);
    v.push_back(t); 
    t.clear();
    t.push_back(1);
    t.push_back(2);
    t.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(t);

    sort(v.begin(),v.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++){
             cout << v[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The question is tagged C; this answer is written in C++.  It shows the disparity between the languages, but doesn't answer the question.